# SUITE CRM 7.5.3 - Installation on Windows 7 / Apache 2.x / PHP 7/MYSQL5.6 hangs after Database Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, apache, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am installing SuiteCRM 7.1 on

1. Windows 7
2. Apache 2.4
3. PHP 7.0.4
4. MySQL 5.6

I am following step by step instructions from suitecrm.com/wiki/index.php/Installation...allation_of_SuiteCRM

This is a local installation and I am not going to send emails. I am going to evaluate whether this is good enough for client's requirements. Based on my findings, I will recommend it to them.

I have tested APACHE, PHP and MYSQL connectivity and all of them work fine.

The installation goes from System Requirements to Database Confiuration & Site Configuration and after filling out all the data there, when I click on NEXT, I see some 25+ messages like this

> "Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; SugarView has a deprecated
>   constructor in
>   C:\Users\Hornigold\MyWebSite\MyCRM\include\MVC\View\SugarView.php on
>   line 44 ?"

And when I click NEXT here, nothing happens..... What do I do.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SuiteCRM 7.1 requires PHP version 5 not version 7. There is some active development in the latest version to support PHP version 7. However it is not ready for production purposes.

An alternative method to installing SuiteCRM on a windows desktop machine is via the bitnami installer.

https://bitnami.com/stack/suitecrm/installer